# How to split fields on a double pipeline

Tags: awk, gawk

I want to use awk to split fields on a double pipeline `||`. Here is my code:

Here is the code that I'm using.

```
BEGIN  {     
    FS="/|/|"  
} 
{ 
    print $2 
    print $1 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use backslashes, not forward slashes to escape the pipe characters. They also need to be double-escaped:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\|\\|"}{print $2; print $1}' <<< "a||b"
b
a
```

The reason that they need to be double-escaped is that they are effectively parsed twice. The first backslashes are lost in the conversion from a string to a regex pattern and the second ones are needed so that the `|` is not interpreted as a regex `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

Some other variations:

```
awk -F"\\\|\\\|" '{print $2; print $1}' <<< "a||b"
b
a
```

```
awk -F'\\|\\|' '{print $2; print $1}' <<< "a||b"
b
a
```

```
awk -F"[|][|]" '{print $2; print $1}' <<< "a||b"
b
a
```

```
awk -F'[|][|]' '{print $2; print $1}' <<< "a||b"
b
a
```